# How to see a terminal output from a previously closed terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I connect to a remote server using SSH

I was compiling using cmake and then make, it's not common to have a progress percentage in compilation process, but this time it has. I was watching the compilation process until my internet connection failed, so puTTY closed the session and I had to connect again to my server. I though that all the progress was lost, but i first make sure by watching the processes list by **ps aux** command, and I noticed that the processes related to the compilation are still running:

```
1160 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/mingetty tty1
 2265 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: root@pts/1
 2269 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
 2353 pts/1    S+     0:00 make
 2356 pts/1    S+     0:00 make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
 2952 ?        S      0:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u
 3085 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
 3089 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
 3500 pts/1    S+     0:01 make -f src/compiler/CMakeFiles/hphp_analysis.dir/bui
 3509 pts/1    S+     0:00 /bin/sh -c cd /root/hiphop/hiphop-php/src/compiler &&
 3510 pts/1    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/g++44 -DNO_JEMALLOC=1 -DNO_TCMALLOC=1 -D_GNU
 3511 pts/1    R+     0:03 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.4/cc1plus
 3512 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

I would like to know if is possible to watch the current progress of the compilation by watching the previously closed terminal output. Something similar like 'cat /dev/vcsa1' or something

Comment: This is off-topic for stack overflow, but you prob want this: http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above, you should have used screen.

As it is, you could try to peek at the file descriptors used by sshd and the shell that you started, but I don't think this will get you very far.